# How to save content from a QTextBrowser to .txt whenever the app is closed?

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

Hope you're having a nice day !

I'm in the process of creating a QT application which is using a QTextBrowser and i was wondering if there was a way to save the content of said QTextBrowser inside a .txt whenever the application is closed ?

Answer (score 0):

Override `QMainWindow::closeEvent`. See [textedit example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/richtext/textedit/textedit.cpp?h=5.15).